# Chrome extension development: Disable browser action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to set the browser action button disabled? or cancel the popup when a condition is true?

Bob

Comment: Ok, I found a workaround: in popup.html ... if (true) window.close()

Comment: For who are finding the way not to display the extension icon with keeping it enable: **it's impossible by Google's policy**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it disable with following code:

chrome.browserAction.enable(integer tabId);

You find more information in the Chrome Apis:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-disable

Answer (score 11):

You can remove popup body with:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: ""});
```

and switch icon to disabled with:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "icon-disabled.png"});
```

To enable, you would need to run those methods again with corresponding params.